# jenkins pipeline failure to run ant

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-pipeline

I've got the following in my pipeline - the main things here are that I'm specifying the versions of both Ant and Java, then I'm telling it which build file to execute.
However it won't even run Ant!

I'm running this on a docker agent - that I've gone into with bash and checked that it can access the relevant ant executable. I've also tried specifying the exact path to the executable - with no luck there either.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                // Get some code from a GitHub repository
                git credentialsId: 'gitcred', url: 'https://github.com/co/thing.git'

            withAnt(installation: 'Ant 1.10.8', jdk: 'latest11') {
                sh 'ant -buildfile folder/build.xml test.thing'
            }
        }
```

It then fails with this:

```
  /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/dugsw@tmp/durable-b810ef86/script.sh: 1: ant: Permission denied
```